# (Variable in separate class) cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java

I am running into this problem that I have not seen before. I have created an integer variable in the `Variables` class. In the `Run` class, I want to check its value, and if it is greater than 0, print `"Hello"`. However, the compiler is giving the error: `"var1 cannot be resolved or is not a field"`. Please note that I **do not** want to call `extends Variables` on the `Run` class. I want to do this without extending.

I have this simple code:

```
public class Run {

    if (Variables.var1 > 0) {  //var1 is underlined, giving the error "var1 cannot be resolved or is not a field"

        System.out.println ("Hello.");

    }

}
```

Other class:

```
public class Variables {

    public static int var1 = 1;

}
```

Comment: Is `Variables` in the same package? If not, have you imported it? If so, try rebuilding your project

Comment: @Bohemian `Variables` is a different class, but it is in the same package. Edited.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, you can't call an `if` outside a method, Java classes must be a set of fields, constructors and method declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Run {
    if (Variables.var1 > 0) {
        System.out.println ("Hello.");
    }
}
```

I don't know if is intentional but this should be:

```
public class Run {
    public void aMethod2Call(){
        if (Variables.var1 > 0) {
            System.out.println ("Hello.");
        }
    }
}
```

You are not following the correct syntax for java.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  public class Run {

    // a If instruction must be inside in a method

    public void someMethod(){
        if (new Variables().var1 > 0) { 
 //var1 is underlined, giving the error "var1 cannot be resolved or is not a  //field"

            System.out.println ("Hello.");

        }
    }
    }
```